# Fail to inject a service to Consumer in a Windows service application (.Net Core 3.1) using MassTransit

Tags: c#, windows-services, masstransit, .net-core-3.1, azure-servicebus-queues

I try to inject an ITest to Consumer constructor in a Windows service application using MassTransit but it fails.

This is what I've tried:

Program.cs

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                ConfigureServices(services);
            }).UseWindowsService();

    private static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddHostedService<TestService>();

        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();
        services.AddTransient<ITest, Test>();
    }
}
```

TestService.cs

```
public class TestService : BackgroundService
{
    private IBusControl _bus;

    public TestService()
    {
    }

    protected async override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.Host("myconnection");
            cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("myqueue", endpoint =>
            {
                endpoint.Consumer<TestConsumer>(); //error when build the project
            });
        });

        await _bus.StartAsync();
    }
}
```

TestConsumer.cs

```
public class TestConsumer : IConsumer<MyTestObject>
{
    private ITest _test;

    public TestConsumer(ITest test)
    {
        _test = test;
    }

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<MyTestObject> context)
    {            
    }
}
```

When I build the whole project I got an error CS0310

> The type ... must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter ...

I searched and they use `services.AddMassTransit` in the `ConfigureServices` function. But in my application I use as a Windows service, not a console application.

So how can I inject my ITest to the constructor of TestService?

Answer (score 0):

You instantiate the bus inside the background service. There's no connection between the DI container and the bus instance. How do you expect anything to be injected into the consumer in this case?

All you need to do is to follow the documentation, and it will work.

[Configure MassTransit for ASP.NET Core](http://masstransit-project.com/usage/configuration.html#asp-net-core) using the example provided, move the bus instantiation to the `ConfigureServices` function, remove your background service and use the provided `MassTransitHostedService` as described in the docs.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMassTransit(x =>
        {
            x.AddConsumer<EventConsumer>();

            x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
            {
                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("event-listener", e =>
                {
                    e.ConfigureConsumer<EventConsumer>(context);
                });
            });
        });

        services.AddMassTransitHostedService();
    }
```

It doesn't matter if you are in Windows service, Docker container, or whatever.

Comment: Ok thanks but what to do with TestService then? I want to start getting the message and stop receiving message in StartAsync and StopAsync.

Comment: Delete `TestService`, the MassTransit hosted service will start/stop the bus.

Comment: Hi Alexey and Chris, thanks for your reply. I've had a look at this https://dgtechboost.com/2020/07/20/azure-service-bus-topic-with-masstransit/ and use the BusHostedService: IHostedService in stead of my TestService.